# How to insert manual line breaks inside LaTeX tables?

Tags: latex

I know that if you define a width in a table's column, you can get automatic word-wrapping.
However, I need to control where newlines should happen in a specific table cell.

Thus, how can I insert manual line breaks in a LaTeX table cell?

Comment: Perhaps, you can try the package `makecell`. Reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475844

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Usually, you use a column definition like `p{3cm}` instead of `l`, and then use `\newline` instead of `\\` in the cell body.

Comment: Could you post an example? I couldn't get a `\newline` to work within a cell of a table...

Comment: This works for me:

    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l|p{10cm}}
      Note:&Here we are!\newline At last!
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}

Comment: I've seen many solutions to this problem and this is by far the cleanest and simplest, thank you

Comment: Is there a equivalent of this for centred columns instead of left-aligned?

Answer (score 29):

You could do it like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  A & B \\ 
    & C \\ 
  \hline
  D & E \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

The command `\shortstack` can be used to wrap cell content and use `\\` inside it:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
one line & \shortstack{two\\ lines} \\
\hline
XX & YYY \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

**EDIT**: however I just realised that interline spacing might differ between your columns. So it's not the prettiest solution.

Answer (score 6):

It can be achieved by using `\newline`. Since, the accepted answer did not have any sample snippet, a working sample is provided here:

```
 \begin{tabular}{p{2cm} p{10cm}}
    \em{Programming} \textsc{languages} & Java, Node.js, Python, Clojure \\
    \newline & \newline \\
    \em{Development systems} & Concurrent Programming, Design Patterns 
 \end{tabular}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do like Bart suggested above and combine with multirow to centralize single line texts.

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Optimized models (Softmax) final results with confidence intervals.}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
         \multirow{2}*{Architecture} & Batch & N. & Learning & \multirow{2}*{Micro-F1} \\
          & size & epochs & rate &  \\
         \hline
         ResNet50& 64 & 60 & $5\times10^{-3}$ & $(\textbf{0.7683} \pm 0.0223)$ \\
         \hline
         ResNet152\_V2& 64 & 40 & $5\times10^{-4}$ & $(0.6698 \pm 0.0467)$\\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
\label{final_result_softmax}
\end{table}
```

#### Yields: [image]

Answer (score -3):

\newline works to break a line within a cell in tabularx environment.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: It does work, so downvotes are not justified, also in tabular environment, at least in paragraph cells (`p`)

Comment: @BBB \newline does not consistently work in tabularx environment. Also, the author did not provide a good explanation for their solution. That's why I think that downvotes are quite justified.